# Windows LOCALE_SABBREVLANGNAME on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, iso, nslocale, lcid

Our application needs to talk to a server component, which (stupidly) takes a Windows language abbreviation (SABBREVLANGNAME) as a parameter. On Mac OS X you can get LCID pretty easily from an NSLocale, but there's no way that I can tell to get the SABBREVLANGNAME. So, I am guessing that I'll need to generate a giant (and I mean giant...) lookup table.

Does anybody know of a good way to do this apart from a lookup table? And if not, does anybody know how to generate such a lookup table, short of writing a small tool in VC++ that dumps this out?

Answer (score 2):

As of Windows 2003, there are only a few exceptions where the SABBREVLANGNAME is different than the ISO code.
You can find those exceptions here:
http://www.siao2.com/2005/02/17/375235.aspx